# Share encrypted sensitive data within different applications in Android

Tags: android, security, encryption

My goal is to share encrypted sensitive data within different applications in Android, for example:

- User signs in App 1
- App 1 encrypts the username
- User opens App 2
- App 2 requests encrypted username from safe common place
- App 2 decrypts username

I have explored [KeyChain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html), but ultimately it is aimed towards SSL and Certificates, not intended for this purpose.

Also, [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) provides safe encryption for 1 app, but it is not possible to share this key safely outside of the one app.

Could anyone please provide some insight?

Comment: There is no "safe common place" that fits your description that I can think of. IMHO, you really should consider having these be one app. You are welcome to have App 2 ask App 1 for the data via IPC (`bindService()` or something based on a `ContentResolver`, most likely), though you will need to take steps to ensure that App 1 and App 2 are each comfortable that the other app is the *real* App 1 and App 2, not hacked copies or malware.

Comment: Are you able to get it resolved? what approach you followed.
As I came across similar scenario and wanted to see some solution here.

Comment: I ended up dropping that approach, but maybe this could be an alternative:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/blob/BlobStoreManager